# @inproceedings in bibTex when something does not work correctly!

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{proposition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=RaggedRight}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2016}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
```

This is my .bib file:

```
@inproceedings{flamm2018dual,
    title={Dual Dynamic Programming for Nonlinear Control Problems over Long Horizons},
    author={Flamm, Benjamin and Eichler, Annika and Warrington, Joseph and Lygeros, John},
    booktitle={2018 European Control Conference (ECC)},
    pages={471--476},
    year={2018},
    month={12-15 June 2018},
    address= {Limassol, Cyprus},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
```

but the month does not work in PDF.

and I use

```
\bibliographystyle{SageH}
\bibliography{refrencesstyle}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small, but complete file?

Comment: If and how the month is shown in the bibliography also depends on the bibliography style you use. Please tell us which bibliography package(s) and which style you use in a short MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that reproduces the output you get from this entry. Note that usually one would think that `month` contains only the month of the publication date and not an entire new date (of the conference).

Comment: The `sageH.bst` file does not output the month, just the year. FWIW that is, I think, correct at least in this case. As far as the bibliography is concerned, the month is not needed to find the resource. If it matters for some reason, you could try putting it in the `note` field. The alternative is to use a different `.bst` file, but if you are using this one because you are aiming to submit to Sage, better stick with what it does, which is presumably what *they* want it to do.